# send me email notification when user signs up for text messages via my twilio-powered application

Tags: node.js, twilio, webhooks, email-verification

I built a basic node.js application where users can sign-up for a weekly email.

Right now, when users sign-up on my website they get a verification email to confirm their number.

What I'd like to do now, is get the application to also send me an email that a user has signed up for the application, once they confirm their number.

Is there a simple way / tutorial on how to set this up?

Do I create a custom webhook for this? here's my .js file below:

```
var client = require('twilio')(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

module.exports.sendMessage = function(phone, msg, callback) {

    // console.log(client)
    console.log(phone);
    console.log(msg);


    client.sms.messages.create({
        to: phone,
        from: '+1XXXXXXXXXX',
        body: msg
    }, function(error, message) {
        // The HTTP request to Twilio will run asynchronously. This callback
        // function will be called when a response is received from Twilio
        // The "error" variable will contain error information, if any.
        // If the request was successful, this value will be "falsy"
        if (!error) {
            // The second argument to the callback will contain the information
            // sent back by Twilio for the request. In this case, it is the
            // information about the text messsage you just sent:
            console.log('Success! The SID for this SMS message is:');
            console.log(message.sid);

            console.log('Message sent on:');
            console.log(message.dateCreated);
        } else {
            console.log('Oops! There was an error.');
        }
        callback(error);
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Nodemailer to have it send you a notification.

https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer

```js
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');


// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'yourappsemail@gmail.com', // sender address
    to: 'yourpersonalemail@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Alert you have a new subscriber', // Subject line
    text: phone+' - has signed up' // plaintext body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);

});
```